# WCF SOAP Service don't return HTTP message body

Tags: wcf, azure, soap

Good day.

We have a PRODUCTION deployment running a WCF SOAP service under IIS, Azure, Web roles.

We recently noticed that some of the requests show a strange behavior, which we can't explain nor understand.

It seems that in some cases the request is processed, the HTTP headers are returned to the client, but no message body is not returned. After about 120 seconds from the request start the connection is dropped.

The HTTP headers include content-length which seems right.

It seems that about 10% of the requests behave this way.

We tried to reproduce in test, but it seems that it only happens under a very high load.

We have tried Streaming ad Buffered TransferMode , didn't see any difference.

We have manually added WCF Diagnostic traces to one of the servers. No errors recorded. Message tracing shows none of the request was processed in more then 18 seconds which is fine to our system.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Br, 
 Hanan

Answer (score 0):

As you doubt that it could be a performance or scalability issue. To drill that down, you first confirm this by

1. Retest the scenarios with a very light load to make sure the code and business functionality is implemented right.
2. Once you make sure that the system is developed correctly, then jump to scalability testing which would give you some figures to identify the benchmarks and how the system is behaving during the scaling process if any such thing is in place.

   Doing scalability test is to increase your load linearly and first figure out what the deployed system or environment capability (CPU/Memory/Network/IO ...) is and when the scaling up rule should be applied. 
   Secondly when you are scaling up, you need to constantly make some requests and confirm that scaling up or down is not effecting the solution.
3. If you are sure that the capacity of system is good enough for your load, then drill it down further to see if there is any underlying DB or sub system is chocked up.

Monitoring your server with a Perfmon tool metrics analysis would give you a better picture to understand the capacity issues.

Note - If you are able to see a consistent faulty behaviour with the responses irrespective of load and even a small manual request is failing then better to look it in a different approach rather than doubting its capacity.